# unable to add single quotes in a bash script to the output of a file which has ssh public key

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting, aws

Assigning SSH key to a variable and assigning that variable to the AWS CLI command

```
auth=$(< /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub)
```

and assigning auth to --ssh-public-key parameter in the AWS CLI command .

Command :

```
aws opsworks update-user-profile --iam-user-arn $arn --ssh-username $user --ssh-public-key $auth  --region $r
```

output is throwing as invalid ssh key as I need to put that in single quotes in the CLI command above. but I am not able to achieve that.

it should be like.

```
ssh-public-key '$auth'
```

However I am unable to append the keys in single quotes in the CLI command .. either a / or additional quotes getting appended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use double quotes. Single quotes will escape the `$` which causes the variable to not be expanded whereas double quotes will only account for the whitespace. Use the following instead:

```
ssh-public-key "$auth"
```